# Which is the fastest way to reach the Scientist's Silo?

Tags: the-cave

I already played the cave two times, so anly the scientist is left.

unfortunately you have to pass all constant caverns to reach the Scientist's Silo:

[image]

So in my third game I will take the monk and ione of the other characters.
To reach the Scientist's Silo I have to cross one of the others caverns too, which one is the fastest to walk through?